# Can I dual boot both windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 on an NVMe m.2 ssd?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, nvme

I want to buy a samsung 960 evo, this is a NVMe m.2 ssd and it is going in the m.2 socket on my motherboard. I want to install both Windows 10 and ubunutu 16.04 on this drive in UEFI mode. Will I be able to boot both operating systems?

Comment: This guy on Reddit seems to know what he's talking about: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3o9xxe/dual_boot_on_a_m2_ssd_is_it_possible/cvvmiea/)

Comment: Some examples. What brand/model system?  Dell with NVMe needs AHCI & boot option nvme_load=YES
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en & ASUS G752 Can't see SSD NVMe Needed UEFI/BIOS update
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307273

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.
Long answer: As long as both can fit on the SSD, the storage type is irrelevant. Just make sure to install windows first and then Ubuntu, since doing it the other way around wipes out the grub dualboot interface and you're just gonna have to go through some extra steps.

Since the the commentators on the other answer necro'ed this question, I may feel the need to address that **never in the past 4 years** has a Windows update ever corrupted neither my dualboot management with grub, nor corrupted my linux install. (Not to mention that a grub fix is easy to do anyway)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this on an Asus motherboard 3 years ago with UEFI on board and it worked fine until next Win 10 upgrade which destroyed Grub.
I still managed to recover it, but recently I received a message that my version of Win 10 (a perfectly legal purchase 3 years old) would end support on October this year, inviting me to install a new release. I did it, and since then good bye Mint (the Linux version I am using) as it boots Win 10 only.
I am really fed up by this and this is why I do not recommend dual boot with Windows: it might work well for a while after a fresh install, but only until next Win upgrade...
So my conclusion is that you should not perform any Win 10 update (at least major ones) if you want to keep a dual boot that really works.

Comment: You can simply install Ubuntu along side of Windows again. It is well known that Windows doesn't respect other operating systems and from time to time erase them.

Comment: its no use doing this, its a unlucky gamble you sometimes makes when windows updates and you reboot , to find your linux installment corrupted,wiped or whatever. You-never-know-when-this-happens !! beware.  thank you ms that is why i run linux only on all my systems.